# Blue screen error while upgrade from ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04 -Different question

Tags: 64-bit

I got blue screen error in my Desktop PC when I'm trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04.

I am able to login from the putty and do the work from the command-line but I'm unable to see the desktop version .

My system configuration is:

```
sanjeet@sanjeet-OptiPlex-790:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 0x29
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6186.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 0x29
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6186.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 0x29
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6186.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
stepping        : 7
microcode       : 0x29
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 4
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips        : 6186.10
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

anjeet@sanjeet-OptiPlex-790:~$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4010976 kB
MemFree:         3615956 kB
Buffers:           57512 kB
Cached:           176884 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           146104 kB
Inactive:         196412 kB
Active(anon):     108912 kB
Inactive(anon):    23316 kB
Active(file):      37192 kB
Inactive(file):   173096 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:       3161560 kB
HighFree:        2897880 kB
LowTotal:         849416 kB
LowFree:          718076 kB
SwapTotal:       4071420 kB
SwapFree:        4071420 kB
Dirty:                56 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        108268 kB
Mapped:            45472 kB
Shmem:             24108 kB
Slab:              26736 kB
SReclaimable:      12080 kB
SUnreclaim:        14656 kB
KernelStack:        2336 kB
PageTables:         3388 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     6076908 kB
Committed_AS:     807952 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:       17576 kB
VmallocChunk:     100016 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     49152 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       43000 kB
DirectMap2M:      868352 kB
```